# React list: index used as keys. Why this code does not cause a bug?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I hear a lot that you're not supposed to use `index` as keys in a React list.

It's even mentioned in the DOCs and I KNOW that it can cause BUGS in some situations.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

But the fact is that I was expecting this code (in the snippet) to be one of the situations where a bug caused by `index` as keys would happen.

Try reversing the order of the array and/or removing the 1st or 2nd item. Or even add an element to the first position, then reverse the order and do it again. It seems to work just fine.

**QUESTION**

Can someone explain to me why a bug isn't happening in this case? And in what case it would happen?

```js
function App() {

  const [myArray,setMyArray] = React.useState(["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"]);
  
  function removeItem(value) {
    setMyArray((prevState) => prevState.filter((item) => item !== value));  
  }
  
  function reverseOrder() {
    setMyArray((prevState) => {
      const newState = Array.from(prevState);
      return newState.reverse();
    });
  }
  
  function addItemToTheTop() {
    setMyArray((prevState) => {
      const newState = Array.from(prevState);
      newState.unshift("New element");
      return newState;
    });
  }
  
  const items = myArray.map((item,index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        {item}
        <button onClick={()=>removeItem(item)}>X</button>
      </div>
    );
    }
  );

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      {items}
      <button onClick={reverseOrder}>Reverse Order</button>
      <button onClick={addItemToTheTop}>Add item to 1st position</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: It dosent says it will throw a bug, but sometimes it may leads to a `performance issue`.... ***REMEMBER PERFORMANCE***. Please refer the article which in deep explains about the performance issue`https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318`

Comment: @AkhilAravind the article explicitly says that **_It may break your application and display wrong data!_** He also adds an example where it does cause a bug. I'm trying to reproduce something similar so I can fully understand it.

Comment: Personally I never put keys, always forget. Never had a single pb yet.

Comment: @NielsDominguez I get triggered by the warning messages. I need to get rid of them all! lol

Comment: @cbdeveloper see the console, there is no error, but the list itself changed. I hope you really get the point. The example itself explains all.

Comment: Honestly I think every react developer has a big yellow console haha. 
I just clean the project when ready to go in production.